# is it good practice to call .Show() or .ShowDialog inside dialog's constructor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, constructor, dialog

Is it a good practice to call .Show() or .ShowDialog() method as the last line of WPF window constructor?
The only reason is to simplify using my window class - by creating an instance of it I'm already displaying it.

Comment: Definitely not. The constructor should only initialize the window, not show it. There are separate methods to do this.

Comment: Thanks all, good to know it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say bad practice. What if you wanted to create instances without showing them?

Instead you could provide a factory method that does this:

```
public static void ShowMyDialog(string text)
{
    // initialize an instance of this dialog 
    // ... and then show
    instance.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: This makes much more sense. Most of the windows I have in my app are simple, I was only creating an instance of them, show and read the input from the instance. The same can be achieved this way, even better.

Answer (score 0):

there is a scenario with inheritance where your suggested approach breaks spectacularly:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "W 1";
        ShowDialog();
    }
}

public partial class Window2 : Window1
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "W 2";
    }
}
```

an attempt to create `var w = new Window2();` will block execution of Window2 ctor until modal window with "W 1" title is closed. `w.ShowDialog()` will throw an exception after that.

under normal coditions user may want to set some properties of Window before showing it, e.g. to set DataContext.

so don't break single-responsibility principle and let constructor and ShowDialog method do their job separately